# Using Phonon in Qt5 - a simple video player

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, phonon, video-player

So what I'm trying to do is stream an ip camera using phonon (vlc backend) in qt5.

I know phonon needs some changes in order to work in qt5 and I've made them, the libraries which used  weren't writable, I made them writable, edited them but I'm still getting lots of errors.
Then I assumed there might be something wrong with phonon! so I downloaded phonon for qt 5. but the result was the same.

even creating an object gives me errors, after Googling my error, I found out there is linking problem but I don't know how to fix it.

.pro file:

```
   Qt       += phonon4qt5
```

header file:

```
    #include <phonon4qt5/phonon/VideoPlayer>
.
.
.
    Phonon::VideoPlayer *videoPlayer;
```

cpp file:

```
videoPlayer=new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory,this);
```

I get these errors:

```
/home/user/Projects/VideoPlayer-Phonon2/mainwindow.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `Phonon::VideoPlayer::VideoPlayer(Phonon::Category, QWidget*)'
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you struggling with Phonon? It's no longer supported in Qt5!
2. Anyway, `undefined references` means that you need to link the library explicitly. You have included with Qt += phonon4qt5, now you have to provide LIBS += -L/path/to/phonon -lphonon4qt5

Comment: We don't always have a choice about our requirements.  I have to either pull in phonon or entirely switch out everywhere it's currently in use...